# smart Raw_Read_Error_Rate

Tags: sata, smart

Need experts opinions. Have disk. Here is smart output of Seagate "Barracuda 7200.10 family":

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   096   089   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       71906027
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       58
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   081   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       121660442
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2600
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       76
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   054   045    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Lifetime Min/Max 33/43)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 8 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   070   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       60991983
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
202 TA_Increase_Count       0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

after "badblocks -wsvf /dev/sdb" smart out is:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   096   089   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       58
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   081   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       122791751
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2603
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       76
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   063   054   045    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Lifetime Min/Max 33/43)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (0 8 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   070   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
202 TA_Increase_Count       0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Raw_Read_Error_Rate = 0 & Hardware_ECC_Recovered = 6 ... how it is possible?

And I have read that Raw_Read_Error_Rate on Seagates has always big value... is it right? is it ok?

Next disk is Western Digital RE3 .. 320Gb .. here is smart:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       890
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   200   200   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       975
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       604
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   107   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

The disk is new... but Raw_Read_Error_Rate is raising .. about +2/+3 per hour... What does it mean? There is no big load on IO ... there 200 web sites... WA in top is less 1% ...

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice question/answer set on this topic over on SuperUser:

https://superuser.com/questions/151288/making-sense-of-s-m-a-r-t